# MongoDB "count" using "$in" becomes too slow

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a big collection (~30millions of records) and I am querying it in different ways, some of them work pretty good:

```
// Query #1
db.getCollection('my_collection').find({ "parent_uuid": "77796c50-7dc3-0134-21f1-0a81e8b09a82" }).count()
// => 415262 (in less than one second)

// Query #2
db.getCollection('my_collection').find({ "parent_uuid": "35529cc0-330a-0135-3ba3-0a901406a434" }).count()
// => 1 (in less than one second)
```

But then I request this and it gets stack

```
// Query #3
db.getCollection('my_collection').find({
  "parent_uuid": { "$in": ["77796c50-7dc3-0134-21f1-0a81e8b09a82", "35529cc0-330a-0135-3ba3-0a901406a434"] }
}).count()
```

#### Indexes

Among other indexes I have this one:

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "parent_uuid" : 1
    },
    "name" : "parent_uuid_1",
    "ns" : "my_database.my_collection"
}
```

I need to use the `$in` option with several UUIDs, what am I doing wrong?

#### Update 1: Explains

- Explain for Query #1: https://pastebin.com/hf33ZWZ8
- Explain for Query #2: https://pastebin.com/fNmj8q70
- Explain for Query #3: https://pastebin.com/WE3AVJCT

Comment: At a very base level then what you are doing wrong is thinking that you "need" a "list" of what is actually "very large strings" to perform a query. The difference between the singular and the `$in` ( which is basically `$or` ) is a known thing, and of course takes considerably more time to seek and merge. The immediate place to start here is to think *"Why do I need these UUID strings?"*. An ObjectiD is guaranteed unique in 12-bytes, and your values are much larger. The next issue is the *"list of values to $in"* and considering the use case of why you actually need to do that regularly?

Comment: @fguillen Have you had a look at what [explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/) can tell you about the different execution plans that are being used for the different queries?

Comment: @NeilLunn : what is the known thing about the $in which means it takes considerably more time to seek and merge? In theory, it could be treated as equivalent to two different singular queries - which should both be fast.

Comment: @VinceBowdren Not really. And mostly because the "total time" is basically equal to the "longest trip", **plus** the time of collation for all individual trips,  if we want to break it down philosophically. Anyhow please don't argue as I simply don't have the time for it. The question is too broad and I am just pointing the OP towards the top two things that are affecting it.

Comment: @NeilLunn I don't mean to _argue_, but I am as interested as the OP in finding out the answer to this. If you could give more detail, perhaps posting it as an answer, that would be welcomed.

Comment: @VinceBowdren Too broad. That's why I'm waiting for the OP to clarify rather than going into it any further. They have given index details in the question, but the issues I see are larger than indexes. Let's just wait for the person who actually asked to respond.

Comment: @NeilLunn I have tried to expose examples that reproduce the issue in the most simple way, my actual scenario is much more complex than this but I narrowed down and remove the noise to make the simplest case. Why am I using UUIDs that long? it might be a bad business decision but it should not distract us for finding what it looks like a weird performance issue. Specially having in consideration that both queries running separately run very fast. It should be a way I can run the query I need without changing the whole structure of my schema.

Comment: I think It would be unwise to think of this as a *"wierd performance issue"* and it would be wiser to take some ownership and realize there are things you could change that make a real difference. So I don't see it as a distraction, but rather the main issue at hand. You can work with it and consider it, or prefer to lay the blame on someone else and get nothing done. Your choice. Merely asked for the justification of why you needed to make large `$in` queries in the first place, since there may be a better way you did not think of.

Comment: @VinceBowdren I have added some `explain()` for the most basic queries in the question description

Comment: Well, the IXSCAN makes it look like your index is present and correct, and the query should be running quickly. Sorry to bother you again, but can you do another explain() with the "executionStats" option to see how it performs when actually run?

Comment: @NeilLunn by the way, maybe this clarifies something, the `parent_uuid` attributes are not unique in the Collection and they make reference to entities not belonging to MongoDB, they belong to another data source

Comment: Then they "still" could be shortened to something that uses less space and `ObjectId` is a reasonable candidate. How about the other side of the issue? How many of these "ids" do you need to supply to `$in` as a typical query? And more importantly Why? This is actually useful to include in your question.

Comment: @VinceBowdren I have added `explain("executionStats")` for the 3 basic queries

Comment: @VinceBowdren I see an interesting difference in the `totalDocsExamined` and in the `executionStages`, but I don't know what are the consequences.

Comment: Well, the results are pretty clear in what is running slowly. The $id query starts off with an IXSCAN stage for both the ids; this is a little slow (745ms), which is perhaps explained by it having to merge the results of two individual IXSCANs. But the subsequent FETCH stage takes a minute and a half (99244ms), so there's the big slowdown.
The individual queries, by contrast, don't have the same query plan at all; they each have a COUNT_SCAN stage followed by a COUNT stage. These use only indexes, and are pretty fast (100-131ms).

Comment: Looks like the query optimiser can't see its way to using a faster query plan. Perhaps it might help if you did a pure `count()` query instead of `find().count()`? Or if you changed the find() to include a projection of just the parent_uuid field?

Comment: @VinceBowdren looks like we have a nice workaround, check the [@Ronna's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44565327/316700).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My hacky solution (and it's still not as fast as it should be) is to use `aggregate` and `group`, then sum the results:

```
db.getCollection('my_collection').aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "parent_uuid": {
         $in: ["77796c50-7dc3-0134-21f1-0a81e8b09a82", "35529cc0-330a-0135-3ba3-0a901406a434"] 
        }
      }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id" : "$parent_uuid",
      "initial_count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id" : null,
      "count": { "$sum": "$initial_count" }
    }
  }
}])
```

will result in:

```
// less than a second
/* 1 */
{
  "_id" : null,
  "count" : 416175.0
}
```

Comment: It works, important to notice that if we use `"_id": null ` in first `"$group"` the execution remains not optimized, this is because another extra `"$group"` is needed to aggregate the partial sums.